# UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm when running LSTM using Tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I'm trying to run a RNN using tensorflow-gpu since with CPU it took me around 13 minutes to treat 1 epoch (8000 pictues in train/ 2000 in test). However, I tried several times the installation of tensorflow-gpu on my Windows 10 but could not manage to run it successfully. I have the following configuration:

GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
GPU 0: Intel(R) UHG Graphics 630
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz

I have the following installed in my virtualenv Tensorflow in pip: [pip packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l23v8.jpg)

I followed the following tutorials:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu
- https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781
- https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-to-Install-TensorFlow-with-GPU-Support-on-Windows-10-Without-Installing-CUDA-1187/

Also since this is a popular issue, i tried different solutions suggested in other topics like:

- compatibility between tensorflow-gpu / CUDA / Cudnn (i tried with different combinations CUDA 9.0/ ..)
- I downgraded my tensoflow-gpu to 1.8.0 but did not worked

Currently, i have tensorflow-gpu 2.00, CUDA 10.0, Cudnn 7.4.1.5, this seems compatible as what is defined (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)
Visual studio is installed and the latest drivers fir my Intel Card.

But i also found that my GeForce GTX 1650 was not mentioned in the NVIDIA gpu enabled for CUDA (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) don't know whether this could be the issue?

The errormessage i get is: UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your images all RGB? I got this error because of a dimension error between the model and the data.

- If your images are grayscale, they will have 1 channel: `(64,64,1)` and will not be compatible with your model's input shape `(64,64,3)`.
- If you images are RGBA, they will have 4 channels, also being incompatible.

Take some time to inspect the results of your generator:

```
print('training data shapes:')
for i in range(len(training_set)):
    print(training_set[i][0].shape)

print('\ntest data shapes:')
for i in range(len(test_set)):
    print(test_set[i][0].shape)
```

Take also some time to plot a few of the images from the generators with their classes.

Comment: The images are RGB based. I didn't expect that the issue comes from the code since it comes from the course tutorial itself (deep learning A-Z of Udemy). I get the following result: (32, 64, 64, 3) didn't let it run for all images since I have 10000.

Comment: Maybe you could let it run for all images, just in case... check `assert img.shape[-1] == 3` in the loop. Your code seems totally ok.  And maybe your problem is not the same as mine, indeed.

Comment: So my training data shapes: (32, 64, 64, 3) and test data shapes: (32, 64, 64, 3) and remarkably 1 case with shape (16, 64, 64, 3). Where to add assert img.shape[-1] == 3? it gave error 'img' not found when putting in the loop.

Comment: `img = training_set[i][0]`. But it seems all ok by your description.